# Force nvidia-driver-450 without 460

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

Because of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-460/+bug/1911055) I would like to install an nvidia driver version < 460 on my ubuntu 18.04.
But whenever I try to install it via

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450`

(also with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` before) it always wants to install `nvidia-driver-460`.

Installing via the .run file from the nvidia website I ran into some kernel module errors.

How can I force to install  version below 460?

Comment: according to package search online `apt-get --dry-run nvidia-driver-440` check this out please. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nvidia-driver-440&searchon=names

Comment: @nobody running that I still get "The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-compute-utils-460 nvidia-dkms-460 nvidia-driver-450 nvidia-driver-460
  nvidia-kernel-common-460 nvidia-kernel-source-460 nvidia-utils-460"
which is exactely not what I want

Comment: Bäh I hate meta packages. Sorry.